# How to traverse a Set[Future[Option[User]]] and mutate a map

Tags: scala

I have a mutable map that contains users:

```
val userMap = mutable.Map.empty[Int, User] // Int is user.Id
```

Now I need to load the new users, and add them to the map.  I have the following api methods:

```
def getNewUsers(): Seq[Int]
def getUser(userId: Int): Future[Option[User]]
```

So I first get all the users I need to load:

```
val newUserIds: Set[Int] = api.getNewUsers
```

I now need to load each user, but not sure how to do getUser returns a Future[Option[User]].

I tried this:

```
api.getNewUsers().map( getUser(_) )
```

But that returns a `Set[Future[Option[User]]]`

I'm not sure how to use `Set[Future[Option[User]]]` to update my userMap now.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to wait for all of the Futures to finish. You can use `Future.sequence` to transform your `Set[Future[_]]` into a `Future[Set]`, so you can wait for them all to finish:

```
val s: Set[scala.concurrent.Future[Some[User]]] = Set(Future(Some(User(1))), Future(Some(User(2))))

val f: Future[Set[Some[User]]] = Future.sequence(s)

f.map(users => users.foreach(u => /* your code here */))
```

However, using a mutable Map may be dangerous because it's possible to open yourself up to race conditions.  Futures are executed in different threads, and if you altering a mutable object's state in different threads, bad things will happen.

Comment: The mutable map is inside of akka.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Future.sequence:

> transforms a TraversableOnce[Future[A]] into a
>   Future[TraversableOnce[A]]. Useful for reducing many Futures into a
>   single Future
>   from [Scala Future](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/Future$.html)

You can try:

```
val result : Future[Seq[Option[User]]] = 
  Future.sequence(
      api.getNewUsers().map( getUser )
  )
result.andThen {
    case Success(users) => 
        users.flatten.foreach(u => yourMap += u.id -> u)
}
```